# ignore .csv.metadata file from athena output

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, amazon-athena

i have a lambda that will query Athena and drop the output of the results in my desired bucket. Athena output contains .csv and .csv.metadata. i don't want to get .metadata file along with the .csv file when my lambda drops it. here is my code:

```
def wait_for_result(athena, query_id):state = athena.get_query_execution(QueryExecutionId=query_id)['QueryExecution']['Status']['State']
    while state != 'SUCCEEDED':
    print('Query state: {}'.format(state))
    time.sleep(5)
    state = athena.get_query_execution(QueryExecutionId=query_id)['QueryExecution']['Status']['State']


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    short_date = event['record']['short_date']

    bucket = 'test-rod-us-east-1-orders'
    s3_output = 's3://{0}/arda-orders/f=csv/short_date={1}'.format(bucket, short_date)

    query = 'query_here'.format(short_date)

    boto_session = assume_role('arn:aws:iam::account-id:role/test-contr-etl-ec2-role')
    session = assume_role('arn:aws:iam::account-id:role/test-xacct-rod-consumer', boto_session)

    athena = session.client('athena')
    s3 = session.client('s3')
    s3_bucket = session.resource('s3').Bucket(bucket)

    response = athena.start_query_execution(QueryString=query,
                                        QueryExecutionContext={
                                            'Database': 'datapond'
                                        },
                                        ResultConfiguration={
                                            'OutputLocation': s3_output
                                        })

    query_id = response['QueryExecutionId']
    wait_for_result(athena, query_id)

    # print ('short_date: {}'.format(short_date))
    for key in s3.list_objects(Bucket=bucket)['Contents']:
       if short_date in key['Key']:
          s3.put_object_acl(ACL='bucket-owner-full-control', Bucket=bucket, Key=key['Key'])
           print('set \'bucket-owner-full-control\' for {}'.format(key['Key']))
             if '.csv.metadata' in key['Key']:
                s3_bucket.delete_objects(
                   Delete={
                     'Objects': [
                         {'Key': key['Key']},
                    ]
                }
            )

             print('deleted {}'.format(key['Key']))

   sqs.delete_message(
       QueueUrl=sqs_queue_url,
       ReceiptHandle=event['receipt_handler']
   )

   print ('Complete process for short_date: {}'.format(short_date))
```

i just get the "deleted key" message in the logs but i still find the .csv.metadata file in the s3 bucket. please help

Comment: Can you assign the result of `s3_bucket.delete_objects` to a name (_e.g._ `response`) and `print(response['Errors'])`

Comment: how do i mention the result of the deleted objects in the code?

Comment: even though there is an error in the lambda, every time a i see a new .csv and a new .csv.metadata file in the bucket. i guess it is dropping the file before the s3.put_object_acl may be

Comment: Use `response = s3_bucket.delete_objects(...` to get the result for the delete request. Then `print(response['Errors'])` to output it. What is the output there?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't delete these objects, they are used by Athena for looking up metadata when you call the `get_query_result` call. Instead of deleting them you should copy the .csv files to another location.